# react native search button in title bar

Tags: react-native, button, header, navbar

Sreach navigation button is not working some can solve my problem
`

```js
<Icon
  name='search'
  type='font-awesome'
  color='#fff'
  onPress={() => navigation ('Linkscreen')} />
      ),
        headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#232C6D',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      },
    };
    };
```

Comment: Saying "It is not working" is not very helpful. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question. We need more code and background information for example.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to call `navigation.navigate('Linkscreen')` instead of `navigation('Linkscreen')`